# Why Does the Input Voltage Drop When a Linear Regulator is Added as Load

Tags: power-supply, dc, linear-regulator, guitar-pedal

Why does adding a linear regulator to this circuit cause the input voltage (V_c) to drop?

[image: Power circuit schematic]

- The 9V input coming in is regulated. The voltage measured at the branch between D5 and R22 is ~8.7 V, so it should not be voltage sag due to the load of the regulator.
- If I remove REG1 from the circuit, V_c reads ~8.7 V.
- With REG1 present, V_c reads ~6.7 V. The drop in voltage is across R22.

The only other place in the circuit where V_c is used directly is to power a 2N7000 MOSFET used as an input buffer.

[image: input buffer circuit]

My best guess is that REG1 is somehow creating a voltage divider with R22, but I did not think this could happen. I don't believe my PCB has any shorts.

Note: I'm actually using a 78L05 regulator. I've tried two different ones ([this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/L78L05ABZ-TR/497-13127-1-ND/3478891) and [this](https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/Products/MC78L05BP(TO-92).pdf)).
The full circuit diagram can be found [here (on page 4)](https://4f3d79f5-cd8b-4c1f-8c04-cc8a4c753d0a.filesusr.com/ugd/ff4c6c_58f8a6b9d0db4a71b1e770234bb0db25.pdf).

Thanks.

Comment: Check TO92 pins 123 = Out-gnd-In

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 REG1 (TO92) pinout is correct. V_c on pin 3, and 5 V out on pin 1.

Comment: Load/Source impedance ratio acts as a voltage divider. Find out where the fault lies.

Comment: Hi, I am not entirely clear on the purpose of having R22 as simply dissipates power and makes all voltages after R22 load dependant. Secondly, Is Vb a voltage reference? if yes, it would be better to create a reference from after your linear regulator. Thirdly, if you see sudden voltage drop without any load, it could be a faulty regulator, if not incorrect pin usage. The use of 2N7000 is not clear aswell in terms of what is outcome you desire from use of 2n7000 circuit?

Comment: I agree but L05 rated for 100mA means 3.3V drop max  If more its a faulty regulator and should be hot

Comment: @NoumanQaiser From my understanding, R22 and C16 are used as a low pass filter to remove 60 Hz hum.

The 2N7000 is used as an input buffer. The guitar signal is coming in through R3 (there's a capacitor earlier in the signal path).

I don't believe it's a faulty regulator since I've seen this happen with 3 different models of regulators that I had lying around.

Answer (score 2):

The regulator needs to have a capacitor, around 0.33uF nearby between input and ground. Also a small capacitor 0.1uF between output and ground is good practice. The regulator could be unstable without it, and without a little bit of load on the output. That *may* explain the current draw, and resulting voltage drop across R22.  Speaking of R22, normally it is a bad idea to have a high resistance on the power feed to a regulator. Also, it is worth noting that the regulator will only work if the voltage drop from input to output is at least 2 volts. So if you need 5 V out, the input pin on the regulator must be at least 7 V.